# How to stop changing date & time in acf field (Date Time Picker / Wordpress)?

Tags: php, wordpress, date, time, advanced-custom-fields

I need to add date & time in an acf field when a user saves a post.
User can only save a post once / Field is Date Time Picker.
The following code adds the date & time when a user saves a post.
The problem is that the time keeps changing to the current time when loading the acf post.
Would you please let me know how to keep the first saving time (stop changing the time)?

Code in functions.php:

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'update_submissiondate_field');
function update_submissiondate_field($post_id) {
    
if (get_post_type($post_id) != 'submission') {
return;
}

$current_user = get_current_user_id();
$current_id = get_the_ID();
$args = array(
'posts_per_page'    => -1,
'post_type'         => 'submission',
'author'            => $current_user,
'p'                 => $current_id,
'meta_key'          => 'doc-submit',
'meta_value'        => 'submit'
             );
$query = new WP_Query($args);
//  echo 'Post';
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
//echo 'Have Post1';
    global $post;
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
            
        $field_key = "field_60c2d9e342189";
        $value = current_datetime();
        update_field($field_key, $value, $post->ID); 
        }   
         wp_reset_postdata();
     } else {return;}
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is just my temporary solution.
If you have better solution, I would appreciate if you could share with me. 
I created two fields: text and time.
Added saving time to a text field.
Then, updated the value to time field.